# Opening pdfs in AI without converting type to outlines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, pdf

I've got a lot of pdfs that I need to open and edit in AI. All the pdfs were created on the same computer, so all fonts are available. However, while some pdfs open ok, others open with the text staying live but not in their original font (this is only a minor irritant, not a major problem) and some open with some or all type converted to outlines.

Is there a way to force AI to open pdfs and never convert type to outlines? 
I'm quite happy to manually specify the font as required.

Answer (score -1):

If you've created the PDF's on the same computer, embed the font while saving/exporting the PDF. This will give you the flexibility to edit the content as text in Illustrator when you re-open it.

Comment: I've created a Brochure in Adobe Illustrator and then I saved it using a Script in PDF format. While saving the PDF or the AI file you're asked to embed the font so that you can use it later to edit the PDF.

Please send the PDF so that I can test it.